# Upgrading matplotlib to 1.5 on OS X 10.11 fails because of freetype

Tags: python, matplotlib, freetype

A simple

```
sudo pip install matplotlib --upgrade
```

fails with the following log:

```
Downloading/unpacking matplotlib from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/m/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.5.0.tar.gz#md5=7952a539418ed77432aa4727409f24cf
  Running setup.py egg_info for package matplotlib
    ============================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: yes [1.5.0]
                    python: yes [2.7.3 |EPD 7.3-2 (64-bit)| (default, Apr 12
                            2012, 11:14:05)  [GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build
                            5493)]]
                  platform: yes [darwin]

    REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                     numpy: yes [version 1.10.1]
                  dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 2.4.2]
                      pytz: yes [using pytz version 2015.7]
                    cycler: yes [cycler was not found. pip will attempt to
                            install it after matplotlib.]
                   tornado: yes [using tornado version 2.2]
                 pyparsing: yes [Your pyparsing contains a bug that will be
                            monkey-patched by matplotlib.  For best results,
                            upgrade to pyparsing 2.0.1 or later.]
                    libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                            be found. Using local copy.]
                  freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype2 (ft2build.h)
                            could not be found.  You may need to install the
                            development package.]
                       png: yes [version 1.6.18]
                     qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'qhull' could not be
                            found. Using local copy.]

    OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
               sample_data: yes [installing]
                  toolkits: yes [installing]
                     tests: yes [using nose version 1.1.2 / mock is required to
                            run the matplotlib test suite. "setup.py test" will
                            automatically download it. Install mock to run
                            matplotlib.test()]
            toolkits_tests: yes [using nose version 1.1.2 / mock is required to
                            run the matplotlib test suite. "setup.py test" will
                            automatically download it. Install mock to run
                            matplotlib.test()]

    OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                    macosx: yes [installing, darwin]
                    qt5agg: no  [PyQt5 not found]
                    qt4agg: yes [installing, Qt: 4.7.3, PySide: 1.1.0; PyQt4 not
                            found]
                   gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
                 gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairocffi or pycairo to be installed.]
                    gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                     tkagg: yes [installing, version 81008]
                     wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                       gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                       agg: yes [installing]
                     cairo: no  [cairocffi or pycairo not found]
                 windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]

    OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                    dvipng: no
               ghostscript: yes [version 9.16]
                     latex: no
                   pdftops: no

    OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
                      dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

    ============================================================================
                            * The following required packages can not be built:
                            * freetype
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ============================================================================

Edit setup.cfg to change the build options



BUILDING MATPLOTLIB

            matplotlib: yes [1.5.0]

                python: yes [2.7.3 |EPD 7.3-2 (64-bit)| (default, Apr 12

                        2012, 11:14:05)  [GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build

                        5493)]]

              platform: yes [darwin]



REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS

                 numpy: yes [version 1.10.1]

              dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 2.4.2]

                  pytz: yes [using pytz version 2015.7]

                cycler: yes [cycler was not found. pip will attempt to

                        install it after matplotlib.]

               tornado: yes [using tornado version 2.2]

             pyparsing: yes [Your pyparsing contains a bug that will be

                        monkey-patched by matplotlib.  For best results,

                        upgrade to pyparsing 2.0.1 or later.]

                libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not

                        be found. Using local copy.]

              freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype2 (ft2build.h)

                        could not be found.  You may need to install the

                        development package.]

                   png: yes [version 1.6.18]

                 qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'qhull' could not be

                        found. Using local copy.]



OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES

           sample_data: yes [installing]

              toolkits: yes [installing]

                 tests: yes [using nose version 1.1.2 / mock is required to

                        run the matplotlib test suite. "setup.py test" will

                        automatically download it. Install mock to run

                        matplotlib.test()]

        toolkits_tests: yes [using nose version 1.1.2 / mock is required to

                        run the matplotlib test suite. "setup.py test" will

                        automatically download it. Install mock to run

                        matplotlib.test()]



OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS

                macosx: yes [installing, darwin]

                qt5agg: no  [PyQt5 not found]

                qt4agg: yes [installing, Qt: 4.7.3, PySide: 1.1.0; PyQt4 not

                        found]

               gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]

             gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairocffi or pycairo to be installed.]

                gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]

                 tkagg: yes [installing, version 81008]

                 wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]

                   gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]

                   agg: yes [installing]

                 cairo: no  [cairocffi or pycairo not found]

             windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]



OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES

                dvipng: no

           ghostscript: yes [version 9.16]

                 latex: no

               pdftops: no



OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA

                  dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]



============================================================================

                        * The following required packages can not be built:

                        * freetype

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build/matplotlib
Storing complete log in /Users/vlad-arisolteanu/.pip/pip.log
```

Meanwhile,

```
brew install freetype
```

returns:

```
Warning: freetype-2.6_1 already installed
```

So it looks like freetype is installed on my system. So what is going on? It's disappointing that such a critical Python package as matplotlib isn't installing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: On the other hand, `ls -l /usr/include/freetype2/ft2build.h` cannot be found.

Comment: Are you attempting to install matplotlib into the system Python? This doesn't seem like you're installing it into a Python that `brew` manages.

Comment: I am installing into Enthought (currently set as the default Python interpreter).

Comment: Since you're using Enthought, the recommended way to get stuff like `matplotlib` installed is to install [Canopy Express](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/package-index/). which is a free add-on to the Enthought distribution that also gives you access to ~100 packages that can be easily installed into Enthought. What you're attempting to do with `brew` and such do not work for Enthought out of the box and would require you to set correct environment variables and build settings, because the system at large is not knowledgeable about `brew`'s existence.

Comment: @birryree that worked. Feel free to post it as an answer, please, and I'll select it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Enthought, the recommended way to get stuff like matplotlib installed is to install [Canopy Express](https://www.enthought.com/canopy-express/), which is a free add-on to the Enthought distribution that also gives you access to ~100 packages that can be easily installed into Enthought.

What you're attempting to do with `brew` and such do not work for Enthought out of the box and would require you to set correct environment variables and build settings, because the system at large is not knowledgeable about `brew`'s existence.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible you need to install `pkg-config`. Try:

```
brew install pkg-config
```

before you install `matplotlib`.

See [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3029/) for more discussion on this. It sounds like `matplotlib` gets confused about the path to `freetype`, but `pkg-config` overrides this and sets the right path. There's also the `matplotlib` readme [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/README.osx) which suggests you need `pkg-config`.

Comment: I've seen this solution before. But brew returns `Warning: pkg-config-0.29 already installed`. Also, `ls -l /usr/include/freetype2/ft2build.h` cannot be found.

Comment: Does it exist somewhere else? e.g. `/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.6.1/include/freetype2`? if so, you could `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.6.1/include/freetype2 /usr/include/freetype`

Comment: Thanks, this has now been answered by @birryree. The more general issue was that I was using a Python interpreter which was not managed by `brew`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using matplotlib, OSX 10.11, Python 3.6 and matplotlib 1.5.1

make `virtualenv` (in a path with no spaces in it)
I already had python 3 installed and I found that giving the symlink didn’t install it, so I followed the `symlink` to the python3.6 file and used that. With the `virtualenv -p` command.

I installed the `xquartz` thing that is not in `osx` by default apparently and `matplotlib` still wouldn’t install. That is, until I found out that the `matplotlib` install thing looks in `/include/ft2buid.h` not in `/include/freetype2/ft2build.h`, so I setup a symlink in library to the `/freetype2/ft2build.h` file and then ran pip install matplotlib and it worked

Python isn’t installed as a framework…

I tried making this file called framework python that reroutes to python or something but that didn’t work
In the end I found a note that said go to folder:

`~/.matplotlib` (literally paste that in the go to folder dialogue verbatim)
then make a plain text file called `matplotlibrc` (no file extension) that just has the text:
backend: TkAgg

and that is what I call voodoo, now the rain demo for matplotlib works

this specific question might only need that one symlink bit, I gave myself the extra complexity of the virtualenv yet I can't remember why.